# Apply function to all dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, sas

I work with SAS files (sas7bdat = dataframes) and SAS formats (sas7bcat). 
My sas7bdat files are in a "data" file, so I can get a list in object files_names.
Here is the first part of my code, working perfectly

```
files_names <- list.files(here("data"))
nb_files <- length(files_names)
data_names <- vector("list",length=nb_files)

for (i in 1 : nb_files) {
  data_names[i] <- strsplit(files_names[i], split=".sas7bdat")
}

for (i in 1:nb_files) {
  assign(data_names[[i]], 
         read_sas(paste(here("data", files_names[i])), "formats/formats.sas7bcat")
  )}
```

but I get some issues when trying to apply function as_factor from package haven (in order to apply labels on my new dataframes and get like SEX = "Male" instead of SEX = 1).
I can make it work dataframe by dataframe like the code below

```
df_labelled <- haven::as_factor(df, only_labelled = TRUE)
```

I would like to create a loop but didn't work because my data_names[i] isn't a dataframe and as_factor requires a dataframe in first argument.

I'm quite new to R, thank you very much if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to think about using different data structures, for example you can use a named list to save your dataframes then you can easily loop through them.

In fact you could do everything in one loop, I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this, but here's an example of one way without changing your code too much :

```
files_names <- list.files(here("data"))

raw_dfs <- list()
labelled_dfs <- list()
for (file_name in files_names) {
  # # strsplit returns a list either extract the first element
  # # like this
  # df_name <- (strsplit(file_name, split=".sas7bdat"))[[1]]
  # # or use something else like gsub
  df_name <- gsub(".sas7bdat", '', file_name)
  raw_dfs[df_name] <- read_sas(paste(here("data", file_name)), "formats/formats.sas7bcat")
  labelled_dfs[df_name] <- haven::as_factor(raw_dfs[[df_name]], only_labelled = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I got  an error invalid type (list) for variable in row : raw_dfs[df_name] <- read_sas(paste(here("data", file_name)), "formats/formats.sas7bcat")

Comment: right, I forgot that `strsplit` returns a list, please see the edited answer

Comment: I couldn't make this work. raw_dfs[df_name] is still a list and should be a dataframe, I think here is the issue. By the way thanks for your help

Comment: yes this is intended, you should subset it with double square brackets if you want to unlist it, like I did in `as_factor` (i.e.,  raw_dfs[[df_name]])

Comment: It did work by adding one more [] to raw_dfs[df_name] and labelled_dfs[df_name]. Really thank you for your help :)